# XSD validator giving org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4 error

Tags: java, xml, xsd

i am getting the following exception when I try to load xsd file .

Exception :

```
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document     
   'jar:file:/XXX.jar!/lib/yyyy.jar!/resources/copyprocess.xsd', because 1) could not  
    find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the 
    document is not <xsd:schema>.
     at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown 
    Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown  
    Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown  
    Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:626)
```

Java code

```
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema =  
    sf.newSchema(getClass().getResource("/resources/copyprocess.xsd"));
```

copyprocess.xsd

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
     elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
     jaxb:version="2.1">
```

i have checked the file exists in the yyyy.jar.resources and root element is as mentioned above.How do i go ahead with this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the path there were two jars (ie jar within jar) and I was doing getResource.In the scenario of jar within jar getResourceAsStream will work.